# Performing Inner Join in NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I keep on getting an exception when making a query in NHibernate.

This is the following query:

```
 //Query tblSentEmails to pull out all of the records according to that lngMergeID
                strQuery =
                    "SELECT strEmailAddress, tblSentEmails.strSubject FROM tblSentEmails INNER JOIN tblRecipients ON tblSentEmails.strEmailSendID=tblRecipients.strEmailSendID WHERE tblSentEmails.lngMergeID ='" +
                    lngMergeID + "' ORDER BY strEmailAddress ASC";
```

And this is the line to execute it.

```
IQuery qryGetMergedEmails = _session.CreateSQLQuery(strQuery);
```

And after this I keep getting an exception stating that there is a recognition error.

This is the original query:

```
SELECT strEmailAddress, tblSentEmails.strSubject
FROM tblSentEmails INNER JOIN tblRecipients
ON tblSentEmails.strEmailSendID=tblRecipients.strEmailSendID
WHERE tblSentEmails.lngMergeID='11099'
ORDER BY strEmailAddress ASC
```

Note that lngMergeID='11099' is just for this example, I'm passing it in via the parameter.

Am I running this query correctly?

Edit: This is my mapping:

```
 public tblSentEmailsMap()
    {
        //Id(x => x.lngEmailID);
        Id(x => x.strEmailSendID).Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.dtmSent).Nullable(); 
        Map(x => x.strSubject).Nullable();
        Map(x => x.strBody).Nullable();
        Map(x => x.strConversationID).Nullable();
        Map(x => x.strConversationTopic).Nullable();
        Map(x => x.strConversationIndex).Nullable();
        Map(x => x.dtmReplied).Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.dtmOpened).Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.dtmClicked).Not.Nullable(); 
        Map(x => x.UserId).Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.blnTrackOpens).Nullable();
        Map(x => x.blnTrackClicks).Nullable();
        Map(x => x.blnTrackReplies).Nullable();
        Map(x => x.blnOutlookRec).Nullable();
        Map(x => x.lngMergeID).Nullable();
        Map(x => x.strSenderEmailAddress).Not.Nullable();
    }
```

No property link to my recipients table. Simply had the PK from the email table and added it via a different query processor.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var list = session.QueryOver<tblSentEmails >().JoinQueryOver(tblsentsmails =>
tblsentsmails.tblrecipients ).Where(tblsentsmails => tblsentsmails.lngMergeID == 11099)
.OrderBy(tblsentsmails =>tblsentsmails.strEmailAddress ).List();
```

Comment: Forgot to mention, there is no property in tblSentEmails from tblRecipients @Feras

Comment: I already solved the issue but thanks for the input. See the answer I posted.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, ended up using the following:

```
                    strQuery = "SELECT strEmailAddress, strSubject from tblSentEmails INNER JOIN tblRecipients ON tblSentEmails.strEmailSendID=tblRecipients.strEmailSendID WHERE tblSentEmails.lngMergeID=:mergeID ORDER BY strEmailAddress ASC";
                var qry = _session.CreateSQLQuery(strQuery)
                    .SetParameter("mergeID", lngMergeID)
                    .List();
```

Ended up working as expected. Maybe not the best solution, but it will suffice for now.